# Requests/Selenium Isn’t Importing the Same HTML as Browser, in Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I’m having trouble scraping Internet Archive for search results. When I use the BeautifulSoup module to read a downloaded HTML file or if I read the HTML from Chrome using Inspect Element, the HTML is shown properly.
However if I try to use the requests module (even urllib.request or requests_html modules), if I try to read that I get different HTML.
If I open the page in Chrome, go to developer tools and press Ctrl+Shift+P, if I search ‘disable’, it shows ‘Disable JavaScript’, so the page definitely uses JavaScript.
I found out you need Selenium to render JavaScript properly. So I tried using Selenium, and it outputs the same broken HTML. I'm sure this isn't bot prevention blocking me from making requests because nowhere in the HTML code does it show a 403 forbidden error.
This is my code so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver=webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://archive.org/search?query=test')

print(driver.page_source)
```

6/09/2023 EDIT:
I've tried making my script hard wait for 10 seconds so JavaScript can render the HTML properly in the Chrome driver. If I can fix the script I will use Selenium's Explicit Wait function because that's loads HTML quicker. So far the HTML appears to render in Chrome but still outputs the same useless HTML.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

driver=webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://archive.org/search?query=test')

time.sleep(15)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
print(soup)
```

07/09/2023 EDIT:
I tried using Explicit Wait to wait for an element but it gave a TimeoutException.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver=webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://archive.org/search?query=test')

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=30).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "container"))
        )
finally:
    print(driver.page_source)
```

Comment: in question you could show what you get in `driver.page_source` and what you extpected to get.

Comment: There is also a python package and api for working with the archive. https://archive.org/developers/quick-start-pip.html

Comment: The whole search result page uses Javascript to render. You must tell selenium to wait for the results to appear rather than immediately fetch the page content , which will only be the html head and the title bar in the body

Comment: @OneCricketeer I tried adding driver.implicitly_wait(15) but doesn't work

Comment: You'll want to wait until something [`is_displayed`](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/#explicit-waits), depending on the elements you want to find (such as the search results)

Comment: @OneCricketeer I tried that it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I hated this

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://archive.org/search?query=test')
while True:
    try:
        shadowHost = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'app-root')
        shadowRoot = shadowHost.shadow_root
        shadowHost = shadowRoot.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'search-page')
        shadowRoot = shadowHost.shadow_root
        shadowHost = shadowRoot.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'collection-browser')
        shadowRoot = shadowHost.shadow_root
        shadowHost = shadowRoot.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'infinite-scroller')
        shadowRoot = shadowHost.shadow_root
        # here each item in the results is in a 'tile-dispatcher'
        cardElements = [root.find_element(By.ID,'container') for root in [host.shadow_root for host in shadowRoot.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'tile-dispatcher')]]
        for el in cardElements:
            print(el.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
        break
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Looks like all the content on this page gets loaded on into nested shadow DOM elements. IDK much about this stuff, but I was able to get the results with this code. I just looped ignoring errors until the data I expected was present.

The actual data in the cards is deeper in even more shadow elements. Hopefully, this is enough to get you started in digging deeper for your data.

I couldn't find a way to cleanly output the page source for parsing with beautifulsoup, but maybe this is enough and you can just get the data using selenium webelements.

Good luck.